# Summary for each page of Report

Tags: birt

I am able to apply pagination to my table content through page break,

but my problem is i am unable to display summary for each page of Report.

please suggest me, to achieve this

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am finding it hard to imagine a report where summary by page would appropriate. But if you have groups you can add a aggregation to the footer and aggregate on groups in the table.

So if your groups are Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and the report runs three pages.

Where Monday and Tuesday fit on the first page, you would have summaries for each

Where Wednesday covers two pages you would only have an summery on page 3